# Why would Hibernate throw a WrongClassException when the FlushMode is set to MANUAL?

Tags: spring, hibernate, exception, jpa, orm

Consider the following scenario -

There are two tables (identical in schema) called `ActiveIssue` and `ResolvedIssue`. When an issue is active, it is in the ActiveIssue table and when the issue is resolved, it is moved to the ResolvedIssue table. Issues can be related to each other.

I have a method that does the following -

1. Get related issues for an issue from ActiveIssue
2. Get related issues for an issue from ResolvedIssue

Before calling this method, I set `session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL)` to avoid the following scenario -

1. Get related issues from ActiveIssue
2. In the background, an issue X gets resolved and moves from ActiveIssue to ResolvedIssue
3. Get related issues from ResolvedIssue (leads to conflict because of issue X)

However, I observe that I run into a WrongClassException even with this logic in place. For instance, I get

```
org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object with id: 123456 was not of the 
specified subclass ... ActiveIssue 
(loaded object was of wrong class ... ResolvedIssue)
```

I am using `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport` and I call `Session session = getSession()` on this object. ActiveIssue and ResolvedIssue both derive from a base class called `Issue`. I use the `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS` inheritance strategy on the base class, so ActiveIssue is mapped to the ActiveIssue table and ResolvedIssue is mapped to the ResolvedIssue table.

I don't understand why the WrongClassException occurs when I have explicitly set the FlushMode to MANUAL. **Shouldn't the objects in the session be consistent?**

Comment: Full stack Trace please!!

Answer (score 1):

> `setFlushMode(...)` : Flushing is the process of synchronizing the
>   underlying persistent store with persistable state held in memory.

In simple it will tell when to update/remove (sync.) data from memory which is taken from DB.

If go through [`FlushMode`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html) you will come to knwo that setting FlushMode to MANUAL means memory will get sync. when you say `session.flush()`.

Consider an scenario where One thread doing the work shifting an X issue from ActiveIssue to ResolvedIssue and at the same time another thread calling `1. Get related issues for an issue from ActiveIssue`

So as per you before calling this you are setting FlushMode to MANUAL so it will not get sync. before query execution. AS per author

> FlushMode.AUTO :
>             The Session is sometimes flushed before query execution in order to ensure that queries never return stale state.

So when you query on table to `Get related issues for an issue from ActiveIssue` an particular issue X (123456) is may be moved to ResolvedIssue by another thread. so the id 123456 is not of type `ActiveIssue` so that your getting this exception

Comment: Why you are using FlushMode.MANUAL for transnational data ?

Comment: I am agree with this answer. According to Hibernate `FlushMode.MANUAL` is useful in read only data to increase performance. This mode is very efficient for read only transactions.

Answer (score 1):

The manual flush mode only affects your current session not any other competing thread. Every thread runs in Isolation thanks to Transactions. When you move an entity from a type to the other, it may be that the current Session holds a reference to the old type(e.g. ActiveIssue ) for a given id, while you try to persist/merge a different type(e.g. ResolvedIssue) entity with the same id.

make sure you always delete the old entry, flush the changes (even on AUTO) and then add the new type for the same id.

Comment: What do you mean by deleting the old entry? The other thread has already deleted the entry from the DB and moved it to the new table. If the session holds a reference to the old object, how can I delete these references?

Comment: If the othet thread deleted it you will get an optimistic locking exception.